# C# "Encoder" with Stringbuilder

Tags: c#, stringbuilder

I am building a program that will ask for a string, encode it, display the encoded text, and then display the decoded text.

I made a char array of most keyboard characters, and a string array of their values.  For example, the letter A equals "1-", letter a equals "2-", and so on.

Here is what I tried to use:

```
protected internal static readonly char[] CHARS = {' ', 'A', 'a', 'B', 'b', 'C', 'c', 'D', 'd', 'E', 'e', 'F', 'f', 'G', 'g', 'H', 'h', 'I', 'i', 'J', 'j', 'K', 'k', 'L', 'l', 'M', 'm', 'N', 'n', 'O', 'o', 'P', 'p', 'Q', 'q', 'R', 'r', 'S', 's', 'T', 't', 'U', 'u', 'V', 'v', 'W', 'w', 'X', 'x', 'Y', 'y', 'Z', 'z', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', ',', '.', '/', '<', '>', '?', ':', ';', '\'', '\"', '[', ']', '{', '}', '\\', '|', '`', '~', '!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')', '-', '_', '=', '+'};
protected internal static readonly string[] VALS = {"0-", "1-", "2-", "3-", "4-", "5-", "6-", "7-", "8-", "9-", "10-", "11-", "12-", "13-", "14-", "15-", "16-", "17-", "18-", "19-", "20-", "21-", "22-", "23-", "24-", "25-", "26-", "27-", "28-", "29-", "30-", "31-", "32-", "33-", "34-", "35-", "36-", "37-", "38-"};

    public static string Encode(string TextToEncode)
    {
        StringBuilder TTE = new StringBuilder(TextToEncode);

        #region Encode

        if (TTE.ToString().Contains(CHARS[0].ToString()) == true)
        {
            TTE.Replace(CHARS[0].ToString(), VALS[0]);
        }

        if (TTE.ToString().Contains(CHARS[1].ToString()) == true)
        {
            TTE.Replace(CHARS[1].ToString(), VALS[1]);
        }

        if (TTE.ToString().Contains(CHARS[2].ToString()) == true)
        {
            TTE.Replace(CHARS[2].ToString(), VALS[2]);
        }

        if (TTE.ToString().Contains(CHARS[3].ToString()) == true)
        {
            TTE.Replace(CHARS[3].ToString(), VALS[3]);
        }

        if (TTE.ToString().Contains(CHARS[4].ToString()) == true)
        {
            TTE.Replace(CHARS[4].ToString(), VALS[4]);
        }

        if (TTE.ToString().Contains(CHARS[5].ToString()) == true)
        {
            TTE.Replace(CHARS[5].ToString(), VALS[5]);
        }

        if (TTE.ToString().Contains(CHARS[6].ToString()) == true)
        {
            TTE.Replace(CHARS[6].ToString(), VALS[6]);
        }

        if (TTE.ToString().Contains(CHARS[7].ToString()) == true)
        {
            TTE.Replace(CHARS[7].ToString(), VALS[7]);
        }

        if (TTE.ToString().Contains(CHARS[8].ToString()) == true)
        {
            TTE.Replace(CHARS[8].ToString(), VALS[8]);
        }

        if (TTE.ToString().Contains(CHARS[9].ToString()) == true)
        {
            TTE.Replace(CHARS[9].ToString(), VALS[9]);
        }

        if (TTE.ToString().Contains(CHARS[10].ToString()) == true)
        {
            TTE.Replace(CHARS[10].ToString(), VALS[10]);
        }

        if (TTE.ToString().Contains(CHARS[11].ToString()) == true)
        {
            TTE.Replace(CHARS[11].ToString(), VALS[11]);
        }

        if (TTE.ToString().Contains(CHARS[12].ToString()) == true)
        {
            TTE.Replace(CHARS[12].ToString(), VALS[12]);
        }

        if (TTE.ToString().Contains(CHARS[13].ToString()) == true)
        {
            TTE.Replace(CHARS[13].ToString(), VALS[13]);
        }

        if (TTE.ToString().Contains(CHARS[14].ToString()) == true)
        {
            TTE.Replace(CHARS[14].ToString(), VALS[14]);
        }

        if (TTE.ToString().Contains(CHARS[15].ToString()) == true)
        {
            TTE.Replace(CHARS[15].ToString(), VALS[15]);
        }

        if (TTE.ToString().Contains(CHARS[16].ToString()) == true)
        {
            TTE.Replace(CHARS[16].ToString(), VALS[16]);
        }

        if (TTE.ToString().Contains(CHARS[17].ToString()) == true)
        {
            TTE.Replace(CHARS[17].ToString(), VALS[17]);
        }

        if (TTE.ToString().Contains(CHARS[18].ToString()) == true)
        {
            TTE.Replace(CHARS[18].ToString(), VALS[18]);
        }

        if (TTE.ToString().Contains(CHARS[19].ToString()) == true)
        {
            TTE.Replace(CHARS[19].ToString(), VALS[19]);
        }

        if (TTE.ToString().Contains(CHARS[20].ToString()) == true)
        {
            TTE.Replace(CHARS[20].ToString(), VALS[20]);
        }

        #endregion

        return TTE.ToString();
    }
```

Decode method:

```
public static string Decode(string EncodedText)
    {
        StringBuilder TTD = new StringBuilder(EncodedText);

        #region Decode

        if (TTD.ToString().Contains(VALS[0]) == true) // [space]
        {
            TTD.Replace(VALS[0], CHARS[0].ToString());
        }

        if (TTD.ToString().Contains(VALS[1]) == true) // A
        {
            TTD.Replace(VALS[1], CHARS[1].ToString());
        }

        if (TTD.ToString().Contains(VALS[2]) == true) // a
        {
            TTD.Replace(VALS[2], CHARS[2].ToString());
        }

        if (TTD.ToString().Contains(VALS[3]) == true) // B
        {
            TTD.Replace(VALS[3], CHARS[3].ToString());
        }

        if (TTD.ToString().Contains(VALS[4]) == true) // b
        {
            TTD.Replace(VALS[4], CHARS[4].ToString());
        }

        if (TTD.ToString().Contains(VALS[5]) == true) // C
        {
            TTD.Replace(VALS[5], CHARS[5].ToString());
        }

        if (TTD.ToString().Contains(VALS[6]) == true) // c
        {
            TTD.Replace(VALS[6], CHARS[6].ToString());
        }

        if (TTD.ToString().Contains(VALS[7]) == true) // D
        {
            TTD.Replace(VALS[7], CHARS[7].ToString());
        }

        if (TTD.ToString().Contains(VALS[8]) == true) // d
        {
            TTD.Replace(VALS[8], CHARS[8].ToString());
        }

        if (TTD.ToString().Contains(VALS[9]) == true) // E
        {
            TTD.Replace(VALS[9], CHARS[9].ToString());
        }

        if (TTD.ToString().Contains(VALS[10]) == true) // e
        {
            TTD.Replace(VALS[10], CHARS[10].ToString());
        }

        if (TTD.ToString().Contains(VALS[11]) == true) // F
        {
            TTD.Replace(VALS[11], CHARS[11].ToString());
        }

        if (TTD.ToString().Contains(VALS[12]) == true) // f
        {
            TTD.Replace(VALS[12], CHARS[12].ToString());
        }

        if (TTD.ToString().Contains(VALS[13]) == true) // G
        {
            TTD.Replace(VALS[13], CHARS[13].ToString());
        }

        if (TTD.ToString().Contains(VALS[14]) == true) // g
        {
            TTD.Replace(VALS[14], CHARS[14].ToString());
        }

        if (TTD.ToString().Contains(VALS[15]) == true) // H
        {
            TTD.Replace(VALS[15], CHARS[15].ToString());
        }

        if (TTD.ToString().Contains(VALS[16]) == true) // h
        {
            TTD.Replace(VALS[16], CHARS[16].ToString());
        }

        if (TTD.ToString().Contains(VALS[17]) == true) // I
        {
            TTD.Replace(VALS[17], CHARS[17].ToString());
        }

        if (TTD.ToString().Contains(VALS[18]) == true) // i
        {
            TTD.Replace(VALS[18], CHARS[18].ToString());
        }

        if (TTD.ToString().Contains(VALS[19]) == true) // J
        {
            TTD.Replace(VALS[19], CHARS[19].ToString());
        }

        if (TTD.ToString().Contains(VALS[20]) == true) // j
        {
            TTD.Replace(VALS[20], CHARS[20].ToString());
        }

        #endregion

        return TTD.ToString();
    }
```

The encoding part of the program works fine, but the decoding doesn't.  It works until it gets to the if statement that converts the lowercase e(the code has "// e" beside it).  When teh e is encoded, the output is "10-".  but when it tries to decode "10-", instead of the letter e, it outputs the number 1.  It looks like the decoder doesn't get all of "10-", just the first character.

Any suggestions on how I can fix this?

Comment: There is a lot of problems in your code. Starting with too many code *(why do not you use for? see optimisation in Ehsan.Saradar answer)*, ending with ambiguous encoding/decoding. But back to your question. Is the problem for each string, or only a specific string has the problem? Please add to question your test string, and requested output *(encoded string)*.

Comment: Your problem is that "0-"  gets processed prior to the "10-" so the second never encounters a match.

Comment: Are you set on a StringBuilder and arrays or are you open to other options that may be easier to more concise to code here?

Comment: Could you give me an example of how a for loop should be used here?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that some "encoded" characters will be processed prior to the full "encoding" is matched as you have written it.

For example

> "20-20-10-11-"

Would progress in your decode as:

> "2 2 1 1A"

Therefore your double digit encoding will not process properly.

To properly address this using your current methodology, you will need to place a leading dash on your matches.

"-10-" match for your "e" replacing with "-e".  Same for all except for the first one which should be matched last through the set for instance if it is "3-02-" your last would be to match the FIRST "3-" without a leading dash "-" character after all the others have been processed.

In other words, walk your string using a leading dash with each encoding, then run another pass through without the leading dash.

Note you will also encounter an issue with your "-" character - it will mis-match as will all your numeric "characters" during the decode process, giving other challenges to work out.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your code is that you are performing a blanket replacement like `TTE.Replace(CHARS[0].ToString(), VALS[0])` which causes you grief if you've already made a replacement that resulted in an ambiguous character.

For example, should you have the string `" 0"` then you would first replace the `" "` with `"0-"` giving you `"0-0"` then you'd replace the two `"0"` with `"53-"` resulting in `"53--53-"`, followed by replacing the `"3"` with `"56-"` giving `"556---556--"`, etc. So, finally, after all of the replacements the string `" 0"` would become `"56191-91-56191-91-56291-91-91-91-91-56191-91-56191-91-56291-91-91-91-"`.

What you need to do is iterate through your text to convert and just map each character once. Here's how:

```
protected internal static readonly char[] CHARS = " AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz0123456789,./<>?:;\'\"[]{}\\|`~!@#$%^&*()-_=+".ToCharArray();

public static string Encode(string textToEncode)
{
    var map = CHARS.Select((c, n) => new { c, v = $"{n}-" }).ToDictionary(x => x.c, x => x.v);
    return String.Join("", textToEncode.Select(x => map[x]));
}
```

That will correctly map `" 0"` to `"0-53-"`.

Now the reverse is almost as simple. Since the encode introduces a `-` it's easy to just split the encoded string by `-` and then map from the numeric figure.

```
public static string Decode(string textToDecode)
{
    var map = CHARS.Select((c, n) => new { c, v = $"{n}-" }).ToDictionary(x => x.v, x => x.c);
    return String.Join("", textToDecode.Split(new [] { '-' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(x => map[$"{x}-"]));
}
```

If I put in `"0-53-"` as the source I get out `" 0"` as expected.

Comment: Did you try the code with other characters? e.g. `"ľšč°ß§"` You list does not contain all characters that can be printed on keyboard. And when the text contains at least one not supported character *(e.g. tab, new line, national characters)* your code crashes.

Comment: @Julo - Yes, that's true. It didn't seem like that the OP was concerned about that?

Comment: I included most keyboard characters. I know there are others, such as the ones you mentioned, but in this example I didn't include them.  This program is largely an experiment, but I would include all characters if I were to distribute it.

Comment: @S.Ferrell - There are 137,439 characters defined in the current [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) standard. It might be a bit impractical to include them all.